# How do i save a "name" from a table into a variable in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM author WHERE email= :email AND password= :pass';
$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$result->bindParam(':pass', $_POST['password']);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$user = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($rows > 0) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
}
```

I'm using this to log people in, the problem is i also also need to save the "ID" from the table into a $_SESSION['id'], i've been checking out some places but they all seem to do weird things and i cant really understand.

what do i need to add so i can save the ID Number (Its just a normal AI Number in the Table) to the Session Variable to use for other things and identify the user?

Comment: Where is the ID coming from? Is it part of `$row`, retrieved from database?

Comment: use FETCH_ASSOC instead of FETCH_NUM

Comment: its from the table in the database, since it SELECT *
i tried Fetch_Assoc too but i cant seem to get it to work either

Comment: for some reason you are trying to assign a session variable before starting a session